# Cannot list Nodes or namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks

When I try to run `kubectl get namespaces` or `kubectl get nodes` commands etc. I am getting this error (I am using Azure Kubernetes Service). I would appreciate any help with this issue.

```
Error from server (Forbidden): namespaces is forbidden: User "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" cannot list namespaces at the cluster scope
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an authorization module error message: as explained in the [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) and, for example, [shown here](https://speakerdeck.com/mhausenblas/kubernetes-security-from-image-hygiene-to-network-policies?slide=29) you need to have the permissions to carry out a certain action (in this case: list namespaces and nodes).

Since you didn't share more background on how this cluster is set up or who is responsible for it, I can only suggest to either reach out to the cluster admin to give you the rights, or, if you've set up the cluster yourself, have a look at the [AD integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/aad-integration), which may be of use here.